# Django:How can i get the value of radio button not checked?

Tags: post, django-forms, django-templates, radio-button, django-views

I'm working on a simple website using Django framework. The website is similar to Kittenwars. 
In my page i have two images with radio buttons and the user must choose one of them. Every image has a score and,when an image wins a vote, his score increases by 1/n where n is the number of vote. However, when an image lost a vote, his score decreses by 1/n.My problem is: how can i have the value of the loser image after the submit of the form?
Here's the code of my template:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <h2>who is the best?</h2><br>
  <div>
     <input type="radio" name="image" id="immagine1" value="{{first.name}}" />
     {{first.nome}}<br>
     <img src="../media/{{first.path}}" width="300" heigth="150"/>
  </div>
     <input type="radio" name="immagine" id="immagine2" value="{{second.name}}" />
     {{second.name}}<br>
     <img src="../media/{{second.path}}" width="300" heigth="150"/>
   <div>
     <input type="submit" value="vote" />
   </div>
</form>
```

And here there is the code of my view:

```
def vota(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        choice=request.POST['image']
            if choice != False :  
        imm=Image.objects.get(nome=scelta)
        i=1.0/imm.number_vote
        imm.score+=i+i
        imm.save()
        context=RequestContext(request)
        return render_to_response('images/Confirmed.html',{'image':imm,},context)
```

SO, how can i get the values of the loser image after the post?
Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can take hidden fields for radio buttons:

```
<input type="hidden" name="myField" value="false" />
<input type="checkbox" name="myField" value="true" />
```

both of the radio buttons have same name. If any of the button is unchecked, the hidden field will be submitted.